# TYPO3 extension; read custom FAL variable in the domain to use in fluid template

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news, typo3-extensions, fal

In my custom extension I introduced a binary variable to the image metadata that needs to be read, similar to the **`"Show in list view"`** of **tx_news**.

With **tx_news** as example I was able to add the variable, the new palette shows the checkbox in the backend and the selection is registered in a new database field in the **`sys_file_reference`** table ...

now I need to use this variable in my fluid templates, and here I lose the trail; the objects are **`items`** and the new variable is named **`opentab`**, I declare the variable as follows in the domain:

```
/**
 * items
 * 
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference>
 * @lazy
 */
protected $items = null;

/**
 * items with opentab set
 *
 * @var array
 * @transient
 */
protected $itemsOpen;
```

this is how I try to read the items with opentab checked:

```
/**
 * Get open items
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getItemsOpen()
{
    $itemOpen = [];
    foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getOriginalResource()->getProperty('opentab')) {
            $itemOpen[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $itemOpen;
}
```

with **`<f:debug>`** in my fluid template I do see the variable **`itemsOpen`** but no value whatever the db contains for this field ...

my TCA for the items:

```
    'items' => [
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => $ll . 'tx_trader_domain_model_object.floorplans',
        'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
            'items',
            [
                'appearance' => [
                    'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
                ],
                // custom configuration for displaying fields in the overlay/reference table
                // to use the itemsPalette and imageoverlayPalette instead of the basicoverlayPalette
                'foreign_types' => [
                    '0' => [
                        'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;itemsPalette,
                            --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                        'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;itemsPalette,
                            --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION => [
                        'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;itemsPalette,
                            --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ]
               ]
           ],
           'gif,jpg,jpeg,png,pdf'
       ),

    ],
```

Comment: How does your TCA look like of your model?

Comment: I added the TCA (pertinent part) to my question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fluid calls magically the getter methods. So try `<f:debug>{object.itemsOpen}</f:debug>`.

The property will stay empty since you do not fill it anywhere. It isn't used in your getter

Comment: you are right, that debug does show content ... is it enough to call this variable in my fluid template (i tried but get unexpected output) or should I fill it somewhere ?

Comment: You don't need the property in your model. Just use it in fluid as a property `<f:for each="{object.itemsOpen}" as="item">....</f: for>` and it will call your `getItemsOpen()`

Comment: your answer is correct, it did not resolve my problem since the `$itemsOpen` interferes with the `$items` array, reading it in a loop of `$items` it breaks it some how, but I start to understand ... I'll post the question I have now separately ...

Comment: minifranske - if you care to look, I think you know the answer ... my new question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47130147/typo3-fal-add-and-read-a-custom-field-in-a-fluid-template